# Build old VC 6 C++ apps on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, sdk, platform, visual-c++

I have old source that needs to be compiled on VC 6 C++ version.
For that I run a Windows 2008 (32bit) virtual machine and installed the 2003 platform SDK.

I wanted to make a new machine running windows 2008 R2 and therefor it is `Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5` available to install.

So here is the question: Does this platform SDK include the old includes, header files and libs so I can compile the sources or is that not possible at all?
Tho I can't install the 2003 platform SDK on the 2008 R2 machine (at least the default setup won't let me do it).

Comment: AFAIK You can use the later psdk, and set the version using WINVER = (I think) 0x0501.  Are you using deprecated windows api calls? What issues do you get compiling the source under later versions of VC++?

Comment: I am not getting any error at the moment because on my old machine all works find, it was more a general question if I can setup VC6++ with the current platform SDK or not. If it is possible in general I will give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, I just copied manually the platform SDK 2003 from the old machine to the new machine, setting up the options/directory settings and compile worked. Seems it works... will investigate more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for everyone to know asking the same: I had no problem installing VC++ 6 on a Win2k8 R2 even with warnings. Moved all SDK Files to the machine as well and manually setup all the include, libs, app pathes in the correct sort order I had on the other machine.
Compiled all components without a problem. So finally it seems it works even with some stress-calls from the setup program that there is no support for this.